# How do I convert UTC time stored in the database to user's browser timezone

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server, How can I convert the time from the database (UTC) to the user's local timezone?

Their timezone isn't stored in the database, so I have to use an external way to convert it (User's local time/browser timezone).

If anyone could help, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Don't try to solve this down in the database. The user isn't pointing their browser directly at a SQL Server instance - there's code running elsewhere, and that code almost certainly has better facilities for manipulating datetime data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to just convert the input into the local user's timezone before inserting it into the SQL Server.

Or maybe you could try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797/effectively-converting-dates-between-utc-and-local-ie-pst-time-in-sql-2005)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will be of very little help here.

If you totally don't know the exact time zone of the end user, you'll have to do client-side conversion with JavaScript:

- [Convert UTC date time to local date time using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript)
- [Javascript to convert UTC to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622142/javascript-to-convert-utc-to-local-time)

Answer (score 0):

If dealing with client timezone, you need to parse date/time at the browser.

I would recommend the [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/) library