# Convert UTC to local time Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to convert UTC time to local time, but the below code is not working. What's wrong in it?

```
var parsedStartDateTime = 
             new Date(moment.unix(parseInt(data['StartDateTime'].substr(6)) / 1000));
var startDateTimeMoment = 
             moment.tz(parsedStartDateTime, tzName);
var formatted_date = 
             startDateTimeMoment.format("MMM DD YYYY h:mm:ss A");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert UTC date time to local date time using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525538/convert-utc-date-time-to-local-date-time-using-javascript)

Comment: What javascript library are you using there? (for moment.unix, moment.tz)? and What is the value of 'StartDateTime'?

Answer (score 0):

Try appending UTC to the string before converting it to a date then use toString() method of date.

Example:

```
var myDate = new Date('7/1/2014 5:22:55 PM UTC');
date.toString(); //this should give you local date and time
```

This code was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6525602/4028085)

Comment: Why the downvote? Someone at least say why you downvoted please?

Answer (score 0):

To format your date try this:

```
var d = new Date();
var formatD = d.toLocaleFormat("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M (%a)");
```

Reference: [Javascript to convert UTC to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622142/javascript-to-convert-utc-to-local-time)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {
var newDate = new Date(date.getTime()+date.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);

var offset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
var hours = date.getHours();

newDate.setHours(hours - offset);

return newDate;
```

}

```
var date = convertUTCDateToLocalDate(new Date(date_string_you_received));
date.toLocaleString().replace(/GMT.*/g,"");
```