# Change time by adding or subtracting in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, timestamp

I have a UTC timestamp in this format: `2016-04-18 14:38:12`

I am using `getTimezoneOffset();`

i think the number from getTimezoneoffset(); is minutes. how can i change the original UTC time into the current time with getTimezoneOffset? possibly just adding and subtracting?

Comment: I would recommend using MomentJs for time related things. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Rastalamm i want to use vanilla js

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622142/javascript-to-convert-utc-to-local-time

Comment: @theCaveat it says toString, what does that do in terms of date? does it convert the date object to local time date?

Comment: @johnny [Date.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) returns the string representation of the date. 
If you want  a more reliable way that works the same across all browsers, you might want to try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13622393/2905091)

Comment: @johnny - vanilla js doesn't account for all kinds of time anomalies (especially when dealing with timezones). Not sure what this project is for etc but momentjs is super easy to accomplish what you're doing.. ex: moment().add(4, "hours");