# How can I find offset of the timezone and get new zulu format of my date?

Tags: javascript, date

I am having the following zulu time

```
2023-09-04T00:00:00.000Z
```

this date is given as output from some library so I know that it is UTC time.
When the library gives that output I need to transform this timestamp time to my local time - because I know that my time is -120 minutes from the UTC the final output should be `2023-09-04T22:00:00.000Z`.

Or let's say that the library gives me this output `2023-09-10T23:59:59.590Z`, I should convert it to `2023-09-10T21:59:59.590Z`.

So I tried first to find out the timezone offset in minutes according to the local timezone of the user.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_gettimezoneoffset

In my case as I said it is -120 minutes. I can't find a way how can I minus this 120 minutes of my initial timestamp and construct new timestamp.

Comment: The final output you want is also UTC time. The `Z` of `2023-09-04T22:00:00.000Z` means UTC

Comment: There is no such thing as "zulu format". Zulu-time is UTC, and UTC does not specify formatting. You're thinking of ISO 8601 and/or RFC 3339, but neither of those are "zulu" (yes, there are google search results for "zulu format" but it's just low-quality content-farm pages repeating the misconception - nothing authoritative).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript to convert UTC to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622142/javascript-to-convert-utc-to-local-time)

Comment: If your offset is -120 minutes, then the equivalent to 2023-09-10T23:59:59.590Z is 2023-09-10T21:59:59.590-0200. The trailing Z indicates UTC (zero offset), so if you shift the time by an offset, it's no longer UTC.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding time... Wouldn't you just want to format/display the time according to your time zone? Substracting 120 minutes to the time would CHANGE the time you want. 2023-09-10T23:59:59.590Z and 2023-09-10T21:59:59.590Z are NOT the same time in different timezone (because Z stands for UTC as others pointed out)

Comment: I do need UTC at the end, I need local time - but  I need to send the same format with Z so it will be accepted by the backend service

Comment: _"but I need to send the same format"_ - then why bother with the local timezone offset at all?

Comment: Because the searches on the BE needs to be done by the dates that are sent from FE - that dates should be in local time - I mentioned that I need to send the same format because there is type safety on BE and the call will fail if I send other format... so BE is not taking the Zulu time into consideration when the dates are sent but only the hh,mm and ss. So i needed just to modify UTC time to local time so some document will appear after we do search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve what you describe here is one solution which might help you.

1. convert the string to a Date object

`const time = new Date('2023-09-04T00:00:00.000Z')`

2. subtract the desired minutes

`time.setMinutes(time.getMinutes() - 120) // or however many you might want`

3. revert the subtracted time back into a human readable string

`const newTime = time.toISOString() // would print: 2023-09-03T22:00:00.000Z`

As other have mentioned already, this might not the best practice. You can write a function which can give you the correct datetime based on the locale (whether that would be from the browser or given as a parameter), or implement an already existing library which can do that for you.

Comment: But the timestamp now represents a different moment in time. Also, *setMinutes* changes the "local" minutes, so in rare cases it might cross a DST boundary and shift by the local offset (usually ±1 hour but maybe ±30 minutes). If the intention is to change the UTC minutes, then use *setUTCMinutes*.

Comment: `newTime` is _not_ `time` in a different timezone.

Comment: Re "*…correct datetime based on the locale*". You are using "locale" in it's correct context to mean place or area. Unfortunately in the context of *Intl* and ECMA-402, "locale" has been (illogically and confusingly) redefined to mean language.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use *toLocaleString* with an appropriate language and offset.

E.g. the following produces "2023-09-03 22:00:00 GMT−2".

```js
console.log(
  new Date('2023-09-04T00:00:00.000Z').toLocaleString('sv',{
    timeZone:'Etc/GMT+2',
    hour12:false,
    timeZoneName:'shortOffset'
  }
));
```

The Etc offsets use the POSIX sense, so +2 is equivalent to GMT-2.

Note that *toLocaleString* is not that reliable for formatting, better to use a library or your own formatting function (which might start with *toLocaleString* or *Intl.DateTimeFormat* to get the parts).

Comment: `sv` is not the right locale to use for RFC 3339 formatted output, because `sv` is specifically for Sweden, and the Swedish government could choose to abandon `yyyy-MM-dd` next week. (In the future we'd be [using the newfangled Temporal API](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/strings.html))

Comment: @RobG this is not dynamic sollution

Comment: @dai— sv is a BCP47 language tag, not a "locale". That misnomer has been propagated by the authors of ECMA-402 (and others).  Please also see the first and last sentences of my answer.

Comment: @AndrejBoskoski—it's an example. If you want it to be dynamic in whatever way you think it should be (such as language, format, timezone, representative location, date or time value), go for it.