# JSON Datetime php object

Tags: javascript, php, json

I send to JS a json datetime object, how i can convert it to datetime JS object?

PHP return:

```
"date": {
  "lastErrors": {
     "warning_count":0,
     "warnings":[],
     "error_count":0,
     "errors":[]
  },
  "timezone": {
    "name":"Europe\/Warsaw",
    "location": {
      "country_code":"PL",
      "latitude":52.25,
      "longitude":21,
      "comments":""
    }
  },
  "offset":7200,
  "timestamp":1399413600
}
```

I need in JavaScript Hours and minutes to easy summarize and display.

Comment: -1 for not performing a bare minimum search of SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416920/timestamp-to-human-readable-format

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631928/convert-utc-epoch-to-local-date-with-javascript/8016205#8016205

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc/6777470#6777470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from JSON to Datetime object using unix timestamp

```
s = '{"date":{"lastErrors":{"warning_count":0,"warnings":[],"error_count":0,"errors":[]},"timezone":{"name":"Europe\/Warsaw","location":{"country_code":"PL","latitude":52.25,"longitude":21,"comments":""}},"offset":7200,"timestamp":1399413600}}'
new Date(JSON.parse(s).date.timestamp * 1000)
```