# Parsing UNIX date from JSON file

Tags: ajax, json, date, unix

Hello stackoverflowers:)

`"Date":"\/Date(1340550000000+0100)\/"` Is what i receive from the json server.

now at the moment when i get information i'm using this code

```
 success: function (json) {



               //var json = $.parseJSON(data);



               for(var i =0;i < json.results.length;i++) {



                 var title = json.results[i].name;



                 var venue = json.results[i].venue;

                 var date = json.results[i].date;

                var button = "<button class='btn btn-info' data-url='"+(i+1)+".html'>Link</button>";







                 $("#apple").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+venue+"</td><td>"+date+"</td><td>"+button+"</td></tr></tbody>");
```

ideally i'm wanting to replace `var date = json.results[i].date;` with the unix date as a readable format, ( can get it in in its current format just its not very readable:)

Thanks

Comment: So this question is not so much about retrieving the result, but rather just converting unix timestamp into human readable format in javascript?

Comment: YEs sorry for not making it clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timestamp to human readable format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416920/timestamp-to-human-readable-format)

Comment: not a duplicate, ive tried that and the datas coming from the server in a different format.