# Why new Date returns wrong date?

Tags: javascript

When I create a new object `var date = new Date(1550571050)`
this returns

> Mon Jan 19 1970 05:42:51 GMT+0700

while it should be

> Mon Feb 19 2019 05:42:51 GTM+0700

whats wrong with it?

Comment: RTM. new Date() expects ms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`var date = new Date(1550571050)` has date `1550571050` which is in seconds.

As described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), `Date` constructor accepts a unix timestamp which is

> an integer value representing the number of **milliseconds**

If you add 000 to your date it will be in milliseconds instead of seconds and the date object will be correct

```
new Date(1550571050000)
// Tue Feb 19 2019 12:10:50 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
```

Comment: @Myrealname if you find some answer on Stackoverflow solves your problem - click a checkmark icon under the voting buttons so it helps other users

Answer (score 1):

in Javascript timestamps are given in milliseconds, not seconds

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this:

```
var timestamp = 1550571050;
var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
```

And refer this:

[Timestamp to human readable format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416920/timestamp-to-human-readable-format)

Answer (score 1):

timestamps are in milliseconds so multiply by 1000. then it will give correct date.

```js
new Date(1550571050000)
```